# Can't verify user login details in Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-studio

Here is the code I used to check if a user is already the part of database or not:

```
  Boolean checkEmailPass = db.emailpasswd(email, pass);
            if (checkEmailPass== false){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email or password incorrect", Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successful Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Below is the code part from `datahelper` class. The name of the table is `user`.

```
 public boolean emailpasswd(String email, String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where email=? and password = ?", new
            String[]{email, password});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have created an application with the help of a SQLite database. The whole application is working fine, but just whenever I am trying to log in, the application is not able to check email and password from the database and that's why no matter what I enter I get the toast of successful login. Please check the code and guide me through.

Comment: Please do not attempt to post an image of the code, you will likely a number of down votes for doing so. Edit your question and then copy and paste the code as a [**MVCE** Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting actual codes makes it easier for others to test the code and thus makes it easier for answers to be provided. Many would simply ignore the question if the code is pasted as an image, others may well down vote the question, others may well vote to close the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have created a with the help of..."*? E.g., is a word missing? Respond by editing your question, not here  in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
if (cursor.getCount()>0){
    return false;
}else {
    return true;
}
```

So if the user exists you return `false`!!!
Change it the other way:

```
if (cursor.getCount()>0){
    return true;
}else {
    return false;
}
```

and put a `db.close()` at the end.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion but I am still stuck with the only difference that now I am getting a email and password incorrect toast instead of a login successful code. p